# the $p$-value definition

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, p-value

I am reading *Introduction to Statistical Learning* by James et al (freely available on their [website](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)). In the section the quote below is taken from, they illustrate how $t$-statistic is used to test the null hypothesis.

Now, I understand the definition of the $t$-statistic. But, I am having trouble wrapping my head around the definition of the $p$-value; particularly, in the quoted text below, which value are they exactly talking about?

> Consequently, it is a simple matter to compute the probability of observing any **value** equal to $|t|$ or larger, assuming $\beta_1 = 0.$

In other words, I would like to know how, in Table 3.1, p.68, the $p$-value obtained?

Comment: I very much recommed [the dance of the p values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OL1RqHrZQ8).

Comment: Duplicates are no problem at all! They allow people to find answers for differently-worded questions they type into their search engine. Which is why *we don't delete duplicates*.